# how can I see what money is coming in in my name

Tags: scams, identity-theft

I think that I someone is pretending to be me an is collecting money that should go to me ( disability insurance claims game winnings etc.) but none of these things are reported due to lack of proof is there any way I can see what money has come into my name I can not report identity theft until I find the money that has been taken

Comment: Can you post your general location? Country and state/province?

Comment: What makes you think someone else is getting your money? Did you have an insurance claim and win the lottery?

Answer (score 10):

There is no centralized database of all financial transactions made by each person. So it is practically impossible to be 100% sure that nobody is stealing your identity.

But one thing you can do which is pretty easy and informative is to ask a credit rating agency for a detailed report about yourself. In the EU that usually doesn't even cost you anything due to the GDPR. But in the US it's more informative because rating agencies are bound to less restrictions about what data they can collect. This should tell you if anyone made any contracts or took any loans in your name.

When you have a specific suspicion about someone impersonating you to a **specific** organization (like disability insurance or winnings of a game you participated in), then you can simply ask that organization about whether they have you on file and what data they have about you. In the EU, you can do that with a GDPR information request. You usually have to do these by letter. There are many templates available all around the Internet.

Answer (score -3):

I'm gonna keep it short and simple if someone is doing identity theft with your information get a good lawyer and also have good proof of what was taken taken from you and also any traces of who it might could be

Comment: This answer appears to be two steps ahead of the question. It assumes that the question author already knows that their identity is being used and that they have proof for that. But what the question is asking is how one can find out that their identity is being used by someone else in the first place.